# How to protect routes with nested layouts in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I have an issue with protecting routes in my nextjs app.

Right now,I have 2 layouts:

1. For auth pages ('/auth/login' and '/auth/register')
2. For all other pages.

Right now I am setting JWT in localStorage ( later on it will be in cookie ), and I want to change app layout depending is JWT in localStorage or not ( without verification rn ).
I want to protect all other routes, so If no token only '/auth/*' can be visited,and also change layout dynamicly.

This is my HOC for layout :

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import type { ReactNode } from "react";

const Applayout = dynamic(() => import("../Applayout"));
const Authlayout = dynamic(() => import("../Authlayout"));

export default function Rootlayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const auth = false;
  const LayoutComponent = auth ? Applayout : Authlayout;
  return <LayoutComponent>{children}</LayoutComponent>;
}
```

And this is my basic hook for auth:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

import { useLogin, useRegister } from "@services/authService";

enum formType {
  LOGIN = "LOGIN",
  REGISTER = "REGISTER",
}

interface Props {
  type: formType;
  authData: loginData | registerData;
}

export const useSubmitForm = ({ type, authData }: Props) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();

  const { mutateAsync: loginMutate } = useLogin();
  const { mutateAsync: registerMutate } = useRegister();

  const submitHandler = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setErrorMessage("");

    try {
      let response;

      if (type === formType.LOGIN) {
        response = await loginMutate(authData);
        const {
          data: { token },
        } = response;
        localStorage.setItem("Bearer", token);
        toast("Successfully logged in!", { type: "success" });
      } else {
        //@ts-expect-error
        response = await registerMutate(authData);
        const {
          data: { token },
        } = response;
        localStorage.setItem("Bearer", token);
        toast("Successfully registered!", { type: "success" });
      }

      router.prefetch("/dash");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        router.push("/dash");
      }, 2002);
    } catch (error: any) {
      const message = error?.response?.data;
      const errorMessage = message || "An error occurred";
      setErrorMessage(errorMessage);
      setIsLoading(false);
      toast(errorMessage, { type: "error" });
    }
  };

  return { isLoading, errorMessage, submitHandler };
};
```

I tried something like this:

```
const auth = localStorage.getItem('Bearer')
```

But with this approach it tels me that localStorage is not defain.

Also, I tried to put 'auth' as a useState, and update it with useEffect but then when login is success for example, I am on page '/dash' but I must reload page to see AppLayout.

Comment: Use `middleware` to protect routes

Answer (score 0):

One reason that localStorage is undefined in nextjs (nextjs default is server side unless you initialize "use client") because local storage works on client side. So "use client" needed to be added at the top of the file. And you need to make below type control and make sure it is in useEffect with empty dependency []; You can do the same with localStorage.getItem("Bearer");

```
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            
            localStorage.setItem("Bearer", token);
            // or let token: any= localStorage.getItem("Bearer")
      
          }
```